# What does this do in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell

```
f = filter . flip notElem
```

I am wondering how this line works, this is a function that should take two strings and return a string.

Comment: Did you try actually calling this function? E.g. the result of `f "abcde" "bad bread is good"`, `f "xyz" "extra credit"` should give you some clues.

Comment: @lisyarus, yeah I did, I'm sorry I meant more in the lines of how it works, I understand it removes occurrences of letters in the first string in the second

Comment: Okay, that's already something worth mentioning in the question, it will help answering it.

Comment: try to do `filter . notElem` first, then add `flip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`flip :: (b -> a -> c) -> a -> b -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) flips the first two parameters of a function. So since [**`notElem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:notElem) takes a value and a list to check if the value is not in the list, `flip notElem :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Bool` takes a list and a value to check if it is not in the list.

We thus will first partially apply the first parameter in `f` to `flip notElem`, and then `filter` a list. Your expression is thus a short form of:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
f xs ys = filter (\y -> notElem y xs) ys
```

It will thus return all elements in `ys` (the second parameter) that are not in `xs` (the first parameter). For example:

```
Prelude> f [1,3,0,2] [1,4,2,5]
[4,5]
```

Both `4` and `5` are elements of the second list, but not of the first one.

Comment: Thank you for your help!